# How to create a dynamic list into a dictionary / creating an 3D Array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, pycharm

I want to have a dynamic list.
What I know about the list is it has 3 dimensions

The size of the third dimension is different

For every result I want one (1) item with the original (train) xy coordinates and another item which is a list of the matches

How long the list of the matches is depends on every result

```
coordinates=[]
for i in range(len(result)):
   xy = []
   destination={}
   destination['train']=result[i]
   for m in matches:
        xy.append(m)
   destination['query'] = xy
   coordinates.append(destination)
```

(Maybe another explaination what I'm thinking about: "coordinates" should be a list with the results, for each result an own dictonary with the original xy-cordinates and the xy matches (the xy-lists have a different lenght for every result. On every loop it should create an empty list "xy" and an empty dict "destination")

This is how the list should turn out:

```
coordinates={
{train: (45,3), query: {(1,1),(2,1)}},
{train: (1,100), query: {(1,9)}}
}
```

so if I do 
`coordinates[1].get(query)`
it shows me
   `(1,1),(2,1)`

Comment: Your "how it should look" section does not conform to {key: value} notation. It was a list, up above, so assuming that's what you meant, your next line is wrong, that's coordinates[0].get(query)

Comment: minor errors aside, it looks like your code already does that, so what's the question? And what is matches? You can't use something that you don't have.

Comment: Hello and thanks for the answer. No it doesnt work like this :/ . Matches : Line 6 of my text: "which is a list of the matches". Hope this helps

Comment: It looks like you want a different 'matches' for each individual result. The input does not provide that. To clarify, this is what I meant when I said "You can't use something that you don't have." Maybe it's a design error before this function, or maybe you're not presenting the inputs correctly.